# Numpy ndarray view method and base attribute

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In Numpy we can make a new array object that looks at same data from another array object
using view method.

Which will make a shallow object of an array.
the new array will have the same data from a existing one (actually reference to it), so the data part of the new array will be just a reference to the data of a existing one!(we can resize the new one without changing the old array shape but they will still have the same data even if the old array elements were modified).

For example:

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>>c = a.view()
>>>c
array([1,2,3,4])
```

c is a shallow copy of a (they reference to the same data but not to the same object):

```
>>>a is c
False
```

However, if we tested c.base to a it give a True:

```
>>>c.base is a
True
```

knowing that both are ndarry objects:

```
>>>type(a)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(c)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

if we tested the type of both a and c we find this:

```
>>> type(a.base)
<class 'NoneType'>
>>> type(c.base)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

My questions are:
-What is .base attribute exactly (is it the data part in ndarray object)?
-Why a and c have different types of their .base?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.base.html

Comment: What is `d`, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [numpy doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.base.html):

`array.base` is base object **if memory is from some other object**.

If object owns its memory, base is None, but if an object is sharing memory with another one (for example is a view of it), the base would be the owner object of that memory. In your example, `c.base` is the object that owns the memory, which would be `a`.

Comment: thanks! so flags.owndata will be just a : return isinstance(c.base,NoneType) if there was a Nonetype.